# I am unable to push the last name as loop ends with third item

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var wingb = [{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
        "Name": "Jack",
        "Unit": "DXMX",
        "Cubicle": "TRV02 02 04 b 001",
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "data": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Unit": "DXMX",
        "Cubicle": "TRV02 02 04 b 002",
    }
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "data": {
        "Name": "",
        "Unit": "DXMX",
        "Cubicle": "TRV02 02 04 b 003",
    }
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "data": {
        "Name": "Jude",
        "Unit": "DXMX",
        "Cubicle": "TRV02 02 04 b 004",
    }
}, ];

var bookedSeats = [];
var i = 0;
do {
    bookedSeats.push(wingb[i].id);
    i++;
} while (wingb[i].data.Name != "");
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly working Whats its intended to do. Just focus on condition `wingb[i].data.Name != ""`

Comment: Let me give a clarity guys.....this is simple to you people but i made it complex with insufficient data.....i just want to push the id of fourth element of the array wingb to bookedseats array which is not possible with my code.....i want the complete iteration and dont want it to be stopped in third item...i hope u guys got it....

Comment: tnx all for sparing ur valuable time and i got it by using one of yours comment........Tnx once again everyone....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
var bookedSeats =[];
for(i in wingb)
{
    if(typeof wingb[i].data.Name!== "undefined" && wingb[i].data.Name !="") 
    {
        bookedSeats.push(wingb[i].id)
    }
}
```

Comment: cool bro....i got it....tnx a lot ......but how its posible....can u clarify in a little detailed manner....

Comment: You can use do{}while() also but in your case do while is not good, also you wrote  wrong condition in your while() statement....

I have iterate each object set through `for( i in....)` which is works with `array` and `object`. IF you pas array then it increment `i` on every iterate. if you pass object then in `i` will be key of each element. I your case `i` increatments because in loop you pass `array`...
`typeof` is check wether element/property exist if not exist then it return undefined

Comment: if you like solution please up vote it and make as correct

Answer (score 1):

Try a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead, using `wingb.length` as your upper bound. That will allow you to loop over all existing elements.

```
for (var i = 0; i < wingb.length; i++) {
   // perform your operations on wingb[i];
}
```

If you need to remove or not operate on elements that don't have a name, use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove unwanted items

```
// this will remove any wingb objects that don't have a name
var itemsWithName = wingb.filter(function(item) {
   return item.Name !== "";
});
```

If you are just wanting to retrieve a single property from a collection of objects, I suggest looking into [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
// converts array of objects to array of ids
var bookedSeats = wingb.map(function(item) {
   return item.id;
});
```

Comment: I don't see any conditions in your code example, but if you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do I may be able to help

Comment: i finally got it rob.....but still thanks for your kind help which made me aware of array.map and array.filter.......

Answer (score 0):

Your third entry has no name. and your while loop will stop if it finds an entry with an empty string ie `""`

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
do {
    bookedSeats.push(wingb[i].id);
    i++;
} while (wingb[i].data.Name != "");
```

with this:

```
do {
    bookedSeats.push(wingb[i].id);
    i++;
} while (i < wingb.length);
```

Comment: It would need to be `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah, i thought that too. until i realized his array starts with `id` 1 not 0. actually. hold on a second. i will update my answer. i didn't see he initialized `i` with 0.

Comment: The array starts with element `0` that has an object with `id: 1`.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes. saw that fixed. i was under the impression he was matching the `id` with `i`. never mind. my bad for wrongly reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

because item (id:3) has name empty string (Name: "") so it doesn't continue to the next one.

```
do {
  if (wingb[i].Name !== '') {
    bookedSeats.push(wingb[i].id);
  }
  i++;
} while (i < wingb.length);
```

Comment: so do while on lengh of array and not until name is empty string. and in the push, add an 'if' to check the name is not empty string instead.

Comment: Its cool again ..... i have tried this but how will u handle iteration in if condition.....if its possible will u spare few mins and comment the code as i am not aware of iteration to minimal extent...